# asp.net add checklist to li dynamatically

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have a div `campaignDiv`

and I want to add `li` to that div and inside that `li` i want to add `checkbox`

i tried this

```
 List<string> comps = getCompainNames();
                for (int i = 0; i < comps.Count(); i++) {
                    HtmlGenericControl newLi = new HtmlGenericControl("li");
                    newLi.InnerText = comps[i];
                    campaignDiv.Controls.Add(newLi);
                }
```

but really I don't know how to add checkbox to that li could u help please?

#### I would prefer input type checkbox rather than asp.net checkbox controller

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do something like this, without using any ASP.NET Checkbox controls:

**Default.aspx**

```
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div id="campaignDiv" runat="server">

    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Default.aspx.cs**

```
string html = "<ul>";
html = html + CreateLiCheckbox("MyCheckbox1");
html = html + CreateLiCheckbox("MyCheckbox2");
html = html + CreateLiCheckbox("MyCheckbox3");
html = html + "</ul>";
campaignDiv.InnerHtml = html;

private string CreateLiCheckbox(string checkBoxText)
{
    return string.Format("<li><input value=\"{0}\" type=\"checkbox\">{0}</li>", checkBoxText);
}
```

Comment: in this case you have added checkboxes without values, right? could you add the valuese please? the value is the same and the test that appears beside the checkbox. In other word, the values should be `MyCheckBox1` and `MyCheckBox2` and `MyCheckBox3`

Answer (score 0):

You should use a [CheckBoxList](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.checkboxlist%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) instead.

aspx

```
<div id="campaignDiv">
    <asp:CheckBoxList 
        id="somecheckboxes" 
        RepeatLayout="UnorderedList" 
        runat="server" />
</div>
```

code-behind

```
foreach (var campaign in getCompainNames())
{
    somecheckboxes.Items.Add(new ListItem(campaign));
}
```